# How to copy a SQL result variable in PHP?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, web

I have the following code that retrieves data into a variable:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ............
```

then i try to copy said variable:

```
if (!$result) {......}
else{
        $ref =& $result;
        $resultCopy = $ref;
        echo '</br></br>SQL STMT EXECUTED CORRECLTY</br></br>';
    }
```

Then i print out a table using $result:

```
....
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>';
 echo $row['name'];
 ....
 }
```

Then i try to print out a table using $resultCopy:

```
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultCopy)) {
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>';
 echo $row['name'];
 ....
 }
```

BUT THE 2nd Table doesnt PRint any data to the screen, just the table headers i declare above the table.

Thanks for any help / php coding guidelines / advice.

Comment: second one is another reference to the same value.  
when you printed the results first time, there was nothing left in result

Comment: well i initally tried $copyresult = $result and that didnt work either

Comment: `while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultCopy)){
   foreach($row1 as $key=>$value){
      c1[$key]=$value;
      c2[$key]=$value;
   }
}`

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
function MakeCopy($result,&$c1,&$c2){ 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        foreach($row as $key=>$value){         
             $c1[$key]=$value; 
             $c2[$key]=$value; 
       }
   }
}
//call the function like this
$copy1=array();
$copy2=array();
MakeCopy($result,$copy1,$copy2);
```

Comment: what does the foreach($row as $key=>$value) do?   i have never seen the => used before.

Answer (score 1):

The first loop through capture each row in an array:

```
$names = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $names[] = $row;
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>';
 echo $row['name'];
 ....
}
```

Now just iterate through the array you made:

```
foreach( $names as $v ) {
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>';
 echo $v['name'];
}
```

Comment: why do you say FOreach($names as $v) ?

isnt php lazy typed and the type of $v wont exist at that time?

Comment: Or does that iterate through the values in the array element?  like if there was name,place,id in one row, that would iterate through each element in the row?

Comment: You got it... it's just going through each array element. $v is just $names[$x] if $x is the enumerator in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

@jordan.peoples

if `$row` is `array(key => value)` like `array('iam' => 'vknyvz')` then
`foreach($row as $key => value)
   echo $key . ' ' . $value //iam vknyvz`

it prints out both key then its value